# Merge objects of an array into one object by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I am trying to merge objects of an array into one if they have the same key.

Having this array:

```
let data = [
  { id: "1", cars: 5 }, 
  { id: "1", pasta: 2 },
  { id: "2", cars: 0 }, 
  { id: "2", pasta: 0 },
];
```

I would like to achieve this:

```
let data = [
  { id: "1", cars: 5, pasta: 2 },
  { id: "2", cars: 0, pasta: 0 },
];
```

I am looking for any solutions, but preferable ES6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that combines the Array `reduce` method and the Object `values` method. One benefit of this approach is that it is O(n) time complexity, which would only really matter if you had a ton of data, but still potentially more efficient than the solutions that include loops inside loops.

```js
let data = [
  { id: "1", cars: 5 }, 
  { id: "1", pasta: 2 },
  { id: "2", cars: 0 }, 
  { id: "2", pasta: 0 },
];

const combined = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  acc[el.id] = { ...acc[el.id], ...el };
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(combined);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
let data = [
  { id: "1", cars: 5 }, 
  { id: "1", pasta: 2 },
  { id: "2", cars: 0 }, 
  { id: "2", pasta: 0 },
]

const result = data.reduce((items, item) => {
  const existingItem = items.find(({ id }) => id === item.id)

  if (existingItem) Object.assign(existingItem, item)
  else items.push({ ...item })

  return items
}, [])

console.log(result)

// Original array is left intact:
console.log(data)
```